# Having trouble with tidyr gather()

Tags: r, tidyr

Hi I am trying to create a long dataframe from Re_NM_df

```
head(Re_NM_df, n = 3)
AustinPulse.Remain AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing
1                 NA                         0                       0
2                 NA                         0                       0
3                 NA                         0                       0
```

However, I get this error

```
RE_NM_Long <- gather(data = Re_NM_df, "NurseMom", "Likely", AustinPulse$Remain, 
AustinPulse$NM1_SpacePump)
Error: `AustinPulse$Remain` must evaluate to column positions or names, not an 
integer vector
In addition: Warning message:
'glue::collapse' is deprecated.
Use 'glue_collapse' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("glue-deprecated")
```

Here is my intended output.

```
     NursingMom                     Remain                    Available
1    NM1_Space                         1                       1
2    NM1_Space                         4                       0
3    NM4_Nothing                       2                       1*
```

*Respondent selected that nothing was available.

I just can't seem to code the gather function well. any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question. It would be great to see an example of what you want the final data frame to look like. To assist, below I have created a reproducible example using `tidyr::gather` to turn your example data into a 'long' data frame.

A key thing to remember when using `gather` is to specify the column names that form the 'key' and 'value' pair. You can also select and exclude columns to gather as an additional argument.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

x <- tribble(
  ~AustinPulse.Remain, ~AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump, ~AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing,
                 NA,                         0,                       0,
                 NA,                         0,                       0,
                 NA,                         0,                       0
)

# gathering all columns
x %>% 
  tidyr::gather(attribute, value)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   attribute                 value
#>   <chr>                     <dbl>
#> 1 AustinPulse.Remain          NA 
#> 2 AustinPulse.Remain          NA 
#> 3 AustinPulse.Remain          NA 
#> 4 AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump    0.
#> 5 AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump    0.
#> 6 AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump    0.
#> 7 AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing      0.
#> 8 AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing      0.
#> 9 AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing      0.

    # here I have excluded AustinPulse.Remain from the gather
x %>% 
  tidyr::gather(NursingMom, value, -AustinPulse.Remain) %>% 
  dplyr::select(NursingMom, value, AustinPulse.Remain)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   NursingMom                value AustinPulse.Remain
#>   <chr>                     <dbl> <lgl>             
#> 1 AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump    0. NA                
#> 2 AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump    0. NA                
#> 3 AustinPulse.NM1_SpacePump    0. NA                
#> 4 AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing      0. NA                
#> 5 AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing      0. NA                
#> 6 AustinPulse.NM4_Nothing      0. NA
```

Comment: thank you. Let me edit the question to show my intended output. I think your code will get me to where I want to be.

Comment: will the code you shared work for my intended output? thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on your data, particularly the column 'Available' and what type of aggregation you are doing. But I have updated my answer to get you a little closer. Hopefully I have answered your question on how to use the gather function. If so please accept.

Comment: thank you! that is exactly what I wanted. Maybe my problem stemmed from not being clear on what I wanted the Available to represent. By the way, where did you pick up your tidyr skills?

Comment: You're welcome. Lots of good resources out there, check out the [tidyverse website](https://www.tidyverse.org/) and an excellent online book [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/). Good luck